# Understanding the method for OpenCL reduction on float

Tags: opencl, atomic

Following [this link](http://simpleopencl.blogspot.fr/2013/05/atomic-operations-and-floats-in-opencl.html), I try to understand the operating of kernel code (there are 2 versions of this kernel code, one with `volatile local float *source` and the other with `volatile global float *source`, i.e `local` and `global` versions). Below I take `local` version :

```
float sum=0;
void atomic_add_local(volatile local float *source, const float operand) {
    union {
        unsigned int intVal;
        float floatVal;
    } newVal;
 
    union {
        unsigned int intVal;
        float floatVal;
    } prevVal;
 
    do {
        prevVal.floatVal = *source;
        newVal.floatVal = prevVal.floatVal + operand;
    } while (atomic_cmpxchg((volatile local unsigned int *)source, prevVal.intVal, newVal.intVal) != prevVal.intVal);
}
```

If I understand well, each work-item shares the access to `source` variable thanks to the qualifier "`volatile`", doesn't it?

Afterwards, if I take a work-item, the code will add `operand` value to `newVal.floatVal` variable. Then, after this operation, I call `atomic_cmpxchg` function which check if previous assignment (`preVal.floatVal = *source;` and `newVal.floatVal = prevVal.floatVal + operand;` ) has been done, i.e by comparing the value stored at address `source` with the `preVal.intVal`.

During this atomic operation (which is not uninterruptible by definition), as value stored at `source` is different from `prevVal.intVal`, the new value stored at `source` is `newVal.intVal`, which is actually a float (because it is coded on 4 bytes like integer).

Can we say that each work-item has a mutex access (I mean a locked access) to value located at `source address`.

But for `each work-item` thread, is there only one iteration into the `while loop`?

I think there will be one iteration because the comparison "`*source== prevVal.int ? newVal.intVal : newVal.intVal`" will always assign `newVal.intVal` value to value stored at `source address`, won't it?

I have not understood all the subtleties of this trick for this kernel code.

### Update

Sorry, I almost understand all the subtleties, especially in the `while loop` :

**First case :** for a given single thread, before the call of atomic_cmpxchg, if `prevVal.floatVal` is still equal to `*source`, then `atomic_cmpxchg` will change the value contained in `source` pointer and return the value contained in `old pointer`, which is equal to `prevVal.intVal`, so we break from the `while loop`.

**Second case :** If between the `prevVal.floatVal = *source;` instruction and the call of `atomic_cmpxchg`, the value `*source` has changed (by another thread ??) then atomic_cmpxchg returns `old` value which is no more equal to `prevVal.floatVal`, so the condition into `while loop` is true and we stay in this loop until previous condition isn't checked any more.

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious for you (I think I did not yet fully understand the question), but ... the `while` loop is a standard way to achieve atomicity, as of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Comment: :Marco13, :Aldwin ok, thanks. Let's take a simple case with 2 threads. If the first one is in the while loop, then, until the second one modifies the value of " prevVal.floatVal", the while loop lasts for the first thread, doesn't it ? But in this case, the operation of incrementation "prevVal.floatVal + operand;" is infinite (until second thread stop it ) and so value stored at address "source" is very high because I do summation with a very large number of "operand" values . Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I understand well, each work-item shares the access to source variable thanks to the qualifier "`volatile`", doesn't it?

`volatile` is a keyword of the C language that prevents the compiler from optimizing accesses to a specific location in memory (in other words, force a load/store at each read/write of said memory location). It has no impact on the ownership of the underlying storage. Here, it is used to force the compiler to re-read `source` from memory at each loop iteration (otherwise the compiler would be allowed to move that load outside the loop, which breaks the algorithm).

```
do {
    prevVal.floatVal = *source; // Force read, prevent hoisting outside loop.
    newVal.floatVal = prevVal.floatVal + operand;
} while(atomic_cmpxchg((volatile local unsigned int *)source, prevVal.intVal, newVal.intVal) != prevVal.intVal)
```

After removing qualifiers (for simplicity) and renaming parameters, the signature of `atomic_cmpxchg` is the following:

```
int atomic_cmpxchg(int *ptr, int expected, int new)
```

What it does is:

```
atomically {
    int old = *ptr;

    if (old == expected) {
        *ptr = new;
    }

    return old;
}
```

To summarize, each thread, individually, does:

1. Load current value of `*source` from memory into `preVal.floatVal`
2. Compute desired value of `*source` in `newVal.floatVal`
3. Execute the atomic compare-exchange described above (using the type-punned values)
4. If the result of `atomic_cmpxchg == newVal.intVal`, it means the compare-exchange was successful, break. Otherwise, the exchange didn't happen, go to 1 and try again.

The above loop *eventually* terminates, because *eventually*, each thread succeeds in doing their `atomic_cmpxchg`.

> Can we say that each work-item has a mutex access (I mean a locked access) to value located at source address.

Mutexes are locks, while this is a lock-free algorithm. OpenCL can simulate mutexes with spinlocks (also implemented with atomics) but this is not one.

Comment: When you say "If the result of atomic_cmpxchg == newVal.intVal, it means the compare-exchange was successful, break" with "do { } while(atomic_cmpxchg((volatile local unsigned int *)source, prevVal.intVal, newVal.intVal) != prevVal.intVal)", but I think that we should write instead : "do { } while(atomic_cmpxchg((volatile local unsigned int *)source, prevVal.intVal, newVal.intVal) == prevVal.intVal)" because we break the while loop when the result of atomic_cmpxchg is newVal.intVal if "*source == preVal.floatVal", isn't it ?

Comment: I think I have understood, could you see please my interpretation in my UPDATE 1 above ? thanks